# pgadmin4: Failed to create the SSH tunnel (on W10)

Tags: pgadmin-4

I am trying to setup a remote and secure connection to my database server running on ubuntu from my notebook with Windows 10. pgadmin4 allows to setup an SSH connection. I can setup the tunnel from the WSL terminal in windows, but I would prefer to set it up in pgadmin4 for convenience. I am not quite sure how to do it right. Whether to use localhost or the actual ip address of the server under the connection tab. Though the error message below seems to point out that the ssh-tunnel itself failed. I am sure that I can ssh to the host and the database is running as well.

I wonder whether it is actually possible to use this option under windows. Do I need to install an ssh client manually?

This is the error message that I get:

> Unable to connect to server:
>
> Failed to create the SSH tunnel. Error: Could not establish session to
>   SSH gateway

Comment: What do your logs say after you tried to connect? (i.e. File -> View Log File)